# Restoring Saved ActionBar optiong chosen setting state when Accessing the Appl after exit

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using SingleChoiceItems in ActionBar using Dialog Builder. I neeed to save the item selected even after exiting the application the restoring the saved setting when accessing the application again.

Prerequisite -- > I saw many examples of shared preferences and onRestoreInstance and OnSaveInstance but i am quite confused. Below is the code wiht explanation of what i did.

**-- Dialog Builder ----**

*I saved the present state of the selected option in - > selectPosition .. Then saving the selectedPosition in the global variable isChecked and setting it to the SelectSingleChoice arguements*

```
private void displaySortDialog() {

    final CharSequence[] sort_options = {"Z-A", "A-Z", "Size"};


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sort_apps));


        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(sort_options, isChecked, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected_sort) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sort_options[selected_sort], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition(); 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose:"+selectedPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               if(selectedPosition == 0){
                  Collections.shuffle(applist);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffles the present order list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else if(selectedPosition == 1){
                   Collections.sort(applist, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorts Alphabetically", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else if(selectedPosition == 2){
                   Collections.reverse(applist); 
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reverses the present order selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               isChecked = selectedPosition;

           }
       });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
    });


    builder.create().show();
}
```

**Using the below code. when i long press the home button of press home buttong from thr application the selected setting seems ok they are selected and saved as i toast the message to make it sure they are selected which seem that onSaveInstanceState is working i guess coz OnSaveInstance Toast msg is displayed..but when i try to restore setting saved through the OnRestoreInsatanceMethod then it doest not work.. After exiting the application the settings go back to default**

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(savedInstanceState != null){ 
    isChecked = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_SORT_ITEM");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RESTORED: "+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//outState.putInt(SELECTED_SORT_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
savedInstanceState.putInt(SELECTED_SORT_ITEM, isChecked);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SELECTED_SORT_ITEM+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

Toast  of **OnSaveInstanceRestore** is shown when i press home buttong from the app or long press home button again select the app. But after exiting the app i am unable to restore the selected settings..

If u can help me with these mnethod or some other method it would be appreciable.

Thanks